# Using Haskell's map function to calculate the sum of a list

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, fold

**Haskell**

```
addm::[Int]->Int
addm (x:xs) = sum(x:xs)
```

I was able to achieve to get a sum of a list using `sum` function but is it possible to get the sum of a list using `map` function?  Also what the use of map function?

Comment: You can simplify you `addm` to just `addm = sum`.

Comment: Note: your addm function is undefined for the empty list unless you do something like Waldheinz suggests.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't really use `map` to sum up a list, because map treats each list element independently from the others. You can use `map` for example to increment each value in a list like in

```
map (+1) [1,2,3,4] -- gives [2,3,4,5]
```

Another way to implement your addm would be to use [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:foldl):

```
addm' = foldl (+) 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Here it is, the supposedly impossible definition of `sum` in terms of `map`:

```
sum' xs  =  let { ys = 0 : map (\(a,b) -> a + b) (zip xs ys) } in last ys
```

this actually shows how *`scanl`* can be implemented in terms of `map` (*and* `zip` and `last`), the above being equivalent to `foldl (+) 0 xs  ===  last $ scanl (+) 0 xs`:

```
scanl' f z xs  =  let { ys = z : map (uncurry f) (zip ys xs) } in ys
```

I expect one can calculate many things with `map`, arranging for all kinds of information flow through `zip`.

*edit:* the above is just a  `zipWith` in disguise of course (and `zipWith` is kind of a `map2`):

```
sum' xs  =  let { ys = 0 : zipWith (+) ys xs } in last ys
```

This seems to suggest that `scanl` is more versatile than `foldl`.

Comment: Ok, it is possible, but I don't think that's idiomatic Haskell. But +1 because technically you're right. :-)

Comment: I think you're cheating here, Will. Basically, I read the question as asking whether you can use the `Functor []` instance to calculate the length of a list; and your answer is that you can use an `Applicative []` instance to do so (basically `ZipList`). I realize I'm "enriching" the question (so to speak) by reading `Functor` into it, but by that argument you are enriching it more than I am, since `Applicative` is more powerful than `Functor`.

Comment: @LuisCasillas the point of this answer is that lists are not sets I guess; their structure (items' positions; first/last element) is perfectly visible; `map` is not just `fmap`. IOW `instance Functor []` talks of lists as sets, since only `fmap` is available &nothing else. with sets there's only membership, no position, so there's no order. we can very well define `Applicative` for lists-as-sets too, with cartesian product the only possible implementation - precisely because there's no concept of position. But with it, inner product becomes another possibility (i.e. `zip`, i.e. `ZipList`).

Comment: lists are [indexed families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family), it seems, or [sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence). If you accept this, you can't object to the usage of `zip`. If you do object, that means that you treat lists as non-sequenced, unordered collections.

Comment: another thing is, the OP isn't saying that `map` is the only function that is allowed. So yes, this answer uses `map`, `zip` and `last`, in effect implementing `sum = foldl (+) 0`, but still, it uses `map` in a non-trivial manner, to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to use `map` to reduce a list to its sum. That recursive pattern is a `fold`.

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
sum = foldr (+) 0
```

As an aside, note that you can define `map` as a fold as well:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
map f = fold (\x xs -> f x : xs) []
```

This is because `foldr` is the canonical recursive function on lists.

---

*References*: [A tutorial on the universality and expressiveness of fold](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf), Graham Hutton, J. Functional Programming 9 (4): 355–372, July 1999.

Answer (score 5):

After some insights I have to add another answer: You can't get the sum of a list with `map`, but you can get the sum with its monadic version `mapM`. All you need to do is to use a `Writer` monad (see [LYAHFGG](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer)) over the `Sum` monoid (see [LYAHFGG](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids)).

I wrote a specialized version, which is probably easier to understand:

```
data Adder a = Adder a Int

instance Monad Adder where
  return x = Adder x 0
  (Adder x s) >>= f = let Adder x' s' = f x
                      in Adder x' (s + s') 

toAdder x = Adder x x

sum' xs = let Adder _ s = mapM toAdder xs in s  

main = print $ sum' [1..100]
--5050
```

`Adder` is just a wrapper around some type which also keeps a "running sum." We can make `Adder` a monad, and here it does some work: When the operation `>>=` (a.k.a. "bind") is executed, it returns the new result and the value of the running sum of that result *plus the original running sum*. The `toAdder` function takes an Int and creates an `Adder` that holds that argument both as wrapped value and as running sum (actually we're not interested in the value, but only in the sum part). Then in `sum'` `mapM` can do its magic: While it works similar to `map` for the values embedded in the monad, it executes "monadic" functions like `toAdder`, and *chains* these calls (it uses `sequence` to do this). At this point, we get through the "backdoor" of our monad the interaction between list elements that the standard `map` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Map "maps" each element of your list to an element in your output:

```
let f(x) = x*x
map f [1,2,3]
```

This will return a list of the squares.

To sum all elements in a list, use fold:

```
foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3]
```

+ is the function you want to apply, and 0 is the initial value (0 for sum, 1 for product etc)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers point out, the "normal" way is to use one of the `fold` functions. However it is possible to write something pretty similar to a `while` loop in imperative languages:

```
sum' [] = 0
sum' xs = head $ until single loop xs where 
   single [_] = True
   single _ = False
   loop (x1 : x2 : xs) = (x1 + x2) : xs
```

It adds the first two elements of the list together until it ends up with a one-element list, and returns that value (using `head`).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question has been answered, but I wanted to add this thought...

```
listLen2 :: [a] -> Int
listLen2 = sum . map (const 1)
```

I believe it returns the constant 1 for each item in the list, and returns the sum!
Might not be the best coding practice, but it was an example my professor gave to us students that seems to relate to this question well.

Answer (score 1):

`map` can never be the primary tool for summing the elements of a container, in much the same way that a screwdriver can never be the primary tool for watching a movie. But you can use a screwdriver to fix a movie projector. If you really want, you can write

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable

mySum :: (Foldable f, Functor f, Num a)
      => f a -> a
mySum = getSum . fold . fmap Sum
```

Of course, this is silly. You can get a more general, and possibly more efficient, version:

```
mySum' :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a
mySum' = getSum . foldMap Sum
```

Or better, just use `sum`, because its actually made for the job.