# Haskell : reference to previously updated elements of list within the update function

Tags: haskell, state

Say I have the following definitions

```
data Book = Book {id :: Int, title :: String}
type Shelf = [Book]
```

Assuming I have a hypothetical function (upd is for update)

```
updShelf :: Shelf -> Shelf
updShelf all@(book : books) = updBook book : updShelf books
```

All fine so far. Now let's say the updateBook function needs to refer to the ***updated*** book three books before it i.e updateBook for book at position 5 in bookshelf need to refer to book at position 2 (assume first three books need no such reference to update). No problem, I say, and modify my code as such:

```
updShelf :: Shelf -> Shelf
updShelf all@(book : books) prevBook = updBook book prevBook : updShelf books
                where prevBook = ???
```

What I need help is with is the prevBook function. Although I am not even sure if I am approaching this problem the right way. So, if you guys have any better suggestion to approach this problem differently, it would be highly appreciated

EDIT:

Thomas M. DuBuisson: Your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12145053/1003417) won't work for me. Here's why:
Assume initial shelf (all) state as

```
Book {id=1, title="a"}
Book {id=2, title="b"}
Book {id=3, title="c"}
Book {id=4, title="d"}
Book {id=5, title="e"}
Book {id=6, title="f"}
Book {id=7, title="g"}
Book {id=8, title="h"}
```

then (drop 3 partialUpdate) is (using only ids rather than entire book statement):

```
updBook 4
updBook 5
updBook 6
updBook 7
updBook 8
```

zipWith' ($) (drop 3 partialUpdate) (all) is :

```
updBook 4 1
updBook 5 2
updBook 6 3
updBook 7 4 -> YIKES! Older version of book 4!
updBook 8 5 -> YIKES! Older version of book 5!
```

In my case, I need books 7 and 8 to be updated against already updated versions of book 4 and 5,not the un-updated ones. I hope you understand what I mean to convey.

Comment: Your problem is broken:  new book4 depends on old book4 and new book 1, and new book 1 depends on old book1 and new book (-2).  This chain of reasoning fails. Can you manually specify how you update a list of 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 books?

Comment: I mentioned that in my post, just ignore the first three books. They don't need reference to any other book to update

Comment: good question, real simple [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12154478/849891). Don't know what the origin for all the confusion here is, people over-think this thing ... [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11951590/849891) is also related.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This trick is related to [tying the knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot): we'll use the answer while computing the answer. For the purposes of illustration, I'll use `type Book = Int` instead.

```
updateShelf :: Shelf -> Shelf
updateShelf shelf = answer where
   answer  = zipWith updateBook shifted shelf
   shifted = replicate 3 Nothing ++ map Just answer

-- some stupid implementation just for illustration
updateBook :: Maybe Book -> Book -> Book
updateBook Nothing          current = current + 1
updateBook (Just threeBack) current = current + threeBack + 1
```

Now, in `ghci`, we can verify that `updateShelf` is really using the updated versions:

```
*Main> updateShelf [1,10,100,1000,10000]
[2,11,101,1003,10012]
```

As you can see, the first three are `1+1`, `10+1`, and `100+1`, and the remaining two are `1000+(1+1)+1` and `10000+(10+1)+1`, and are therefore using the updated previous values, just as you'd hope.

Comment: Hey Thanks! Your code works just the way I want it to :) I had been trying to get my head around this for 2 days. Guess I should have come to SO sooner....

Comment: "tying-the-knot" means referring to as-yet-unknown parts of an answer when (gradually) computing new parts of an answer (i.e. using _forward_ pointers (and, arranging for them to be "set" in a language which forbids explicit _set_ operations)). This situation is the ***opposite*** - the known, already computed parts of an answer are referenced (i.e. using simple back pointers), like in the basic `fibs` definition.

Comment: @WillNess This is why I only claimed it was related to tying the knot, not that it actually _was_ tying the knot. =)

Answer (score 6):

there is no knots to be tied here, no back flow of information, no passing around of forward references to a not-yet-defined values. Quite the contrary, we refer back to the known, already computed values. It works even without lazy evaluation. This:

```
updShelf shelf@(a : b : c : t) = xs where
   xs = a : b : c : zipWith updBook t xs
```

is all you need. All that it is "doing", is maintaining an **explicit back pointer** into a sequence being produced, three notches back. *"Back pointers are easy"*, to quote the [haskellwiki's page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) on tying the knot.

Each invocation of `updBook` receives two arguments here - one an item at position `i+3` in the original list, and another a newly updated item at position `i`.

Compare it with this piece of Haskell lore:

```
g (a,b) = xs where
   xs = a : b : zipWith (+) xs (tail xs)
```

There is no knot-tying going on here as well.

Answer (score 5):

First thing: your `updShelf` is `map updBook`.

Second: I think that a list of books might not be the best data structure for your problem, because lists don't support random access operations.  You might want to try using an array if you really need random access at any point in your computation—see [`Data.Array`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Data-Array.html).

Now to my main point: the sort of thing you're trying to do—have a computation that consumes parts of its own result—is frequently referred to in the Haskell community by the names "tying the knot" or the "credit card transformation" (buy now, pay later).  Basically, it boils down to the fact that the following sort of expression is valid in Haskell:

```
let result = f result in result  -- apply f to its own result
```

How can that possibly work?  Well, first of all, as you certainly know, Haskell is lazy, so such a computation is not *necessarily* circular.  Second, it doesn't work with just any computation; there has to be a non-circular, terminating order in which the substeps of the computation can be performed.

So for example, this `cycle` function makes a circular list out of `xs` by appending the result of `cycle xs` to `xs`:

```
cycle xs = let result = xs ++ result in result
```

The "tying the knot" pattern can be abstracted with the library function `fix`, which I show here together with its use:

```
fix f = let result = f result in result
cycle xs = fix (xs++)
```

So in your case, what I would recommend is:

- Use a lazy array (like Haskell's built-in `Array` type) to represent the Shelf; this gives you random access to elements.
- Use the knot-tying technique to refer to the result `Array` during the computation.

Comment: The book and the shelf analogy is hypothetical. The actual problem I am trying to solve would have needed a lot of context. I can't switch to array without at this point without breaking a lot of code. Thanks for the highly detailed explanation!

Comment: You might still be able to use an array as the data structure for this particular problem.  I.e., to solve the problem, read the list into an array, process the array, then turn the resulting array back into a list.  But more generally, you seem to be struggling with making lists do what you want them to; this seems to call for either a change of data structure, or an enrichment thereof (make an intermediate list whose elements are `(Book, context)` pairs).

Comment: The problem does not require random access, it requires access to items 3 apart, so arrays are unnecessary here (and less idiomatic).

Comment: Hi, check out [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12154478/849891). :) good call about `updShelf` being just `map updBook`, next thing to notice is that [`zipWith` is a kind of map too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11951590/849891).

Comment: @AndrewC: strictly speaking the problem does not require random access, but lists don't exactly easily support a "see the element three before me in the result of mapping over this list" operation either—and you never know if the "three before" requirement may change to something stranger later on. An array simplifies the solution and makes it easier to change later on, IMO.

Comment: @WillNess: fun fact: [`map` in Scheme](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#map) is actually a variable-arity `zipWith`. (And of course, the deeper observation here is that `ZipList` is an instance of `Applicative`.)

Comment: (about map) yes exactly. (about lists vs arrays) not necessarily. It is *very easy* to carry around an additional argument, a reference into a list that is several steps back, and call `tail` to advance along the list when needed. Lists are also more local than arrays - discarded prefixes are far easier to get destroyed by GC. And here especially the "phase shift" (so to speak) is constant, so lists are a natural fit IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two parts, first you partially apply updBook to all books, thus making a list of functions then you apply each of those functions to the proper previous book via a zip:

```
updShelf :: Shelf -> Shelf
updShelf [] = []
updShelf all@(book:books) = 
    let partialUpdate = map updBook all :: Book -> Shelf
    in zipWith ($) (drop 3 partialUpdate) all

updBook :: Book -> Book -> Shelf
updBook = undefined
```

Notice this has odd behavior at the start - it just makes the new list three elements shorter because of the `drop 3`.  That isn't required, you could make that line read `zipWith ($) partialUPdate (drop (len-3) (cycle all))`, but you never specified what happens at the start of the list where there are no previous books.

Comment: This won't work for me. See the EDIT in my original post to see explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As a recursive function, `updShelf` won't be able to access elements that it hasn't been passed (so if it gets a list that starts at `bookFive`, it won't have access to `bookThree`.

If you want to write the function recursively, you need to do some more pattern matching:

```
updShelf :: Shelf -> Shelf
updShelf (bookOne : bookTwo: bookThree : books) 
    = (updBook bookOne bookThree) : (updShelf $ bookTwo : bookThree : books)

updBook :: Book -> Book -> Shelf
updBook twoEarlier current = {- undefined -}
```

Comment: sorry, but your `updShelf` accesses only old books. It does not access updated books. The OP wants to combine old "book" at position `i+3` with the *new* "book" at position `i`.

Comment: @WillNess: I had written that answer before OP clarified what they wanted. Mainly my goal was to show that you can pattern-match several `cons`s

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is a flexible way to achieve this:

```
updateOne book = undefined
updateTwo prevUpdatedBook book = undefined

updateBooks books = answer
  where numEasy = 3
        (easy,hard) = splitAt numEasy books
        answer = mapOnto updateOne easy (zipWith updateTwo answer hard)

-- More efficient that (map f xs ++ end)
mapOnto f xs end = foldr ((:) . f) end xs
```