# Is it possible to define foldr using map?

Tags: haskell, fold, higher-order-functions, map-function

After I defined `map` using `foldr` a question came to my mind:

If it is possible to define `map` using `foldr`, what about the opposite?

From my point of view it is not possible, but I can't find a proper explanation.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `map` outputs a list of the same length it gets. `foldr` can output a list of any length, or something that is not a list at all.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: http://web.jaguarpaw.co.uk/~tom/blog/posts/2012-11-04-what-is-foldr-made-of.html

Comment: You have to be a little more specific. Note that it's possible to define `foldr` without using anything but pattern matching, so you certainly can define it using pattern matching *and* `map`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's start with some type signatures.

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

We can simulate `map` using `fold` because `fold` is a universal operator ([here](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/fold.pdf)'s a more mathematical yet quite friendly paper on this property).

I'm sure that there's some creative way of using `map` to simulate `foldr`. That can certainly be a fun exercise. But I don't think there's a straight-forward, not "crazy pointfree" solution, and in order to explain it let's forget about `foldr` for a moment and concentrate on a much simpler accumulation function:

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
```

`sum == foldr (+) 0`, which means `foldr` implements `sum`. If we can implement `foldr` with `map` we can definitely implement `sum` with `map`. Can we do it?

I think `sum`'s signature is a crashing blow - `sum` returns an `Int`, and `map` always returns a list of something. So maybe `map` can do the heavy-lifting, but we'll still need another function of type `[a] -> a` in order to get the final result. In our case, we'll need a function of type `[Int] -> Int`. Which is quite unfortunate, because that's exactly what we were trying to avoid in the first place.

So I guess the answer is: you can implement `foldr` using `map` - but it'll probably require using `foldr` :)

Comment: While reading this I couldn't stop thinking "Curry-Howard strikes again" ;-)

Comment: if `zip` is allowed, [`scanl` *can* be implemented with `map`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11951590/849891), and with the addition of `last` - also `foldl`, and `sum` in particular. lazy `foldr` on infinite lists might be  problem.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to look at it is to see that `map` preserves the spine of the list. If you look at the more general fmap (which is map, but not just for lists but for `Functor`s in general), it's even a law that

```
fmap id = id
```

There are many ways to "cheat," but in the most direct interpretation of your question, folds are simply more general than maps. There is a nice trick that's used in Edward Kmett's Lens library quite a lot. Consider the `Const` monad, which is defined as follows:

```
newtype Const a b = Const { runConst :: a }

instance Functor (Const a) where fmap _ (Const a) = Const a
instance (Monoid a) => Monad (Const a) where
    return _ = Const mempty
    Const a >>= Const b = Const (a <> b)
```

Now you *can* formulate a fold in terms of the monadic map operation `mapM`, as long as the result type is monoidal:

```
fold :: Monoid m => [m] -> m
fold = runConst . mapM Const
```

Comment: Of course, this is still just a fold. It's just had the combiner and zero elements distributed through the monoid.

Comment: `Const a >>= Const b = Const (a <> b)` does not typecheck.

Answer (score 2):

If you make some sort of cheating helper function:

```
f [x] a = x a
f (x:xs) a = f xs (x a)

foldr g i xs = f (map g $ reverse xs) i
```

Comment: this `f` is `f = foldl (>>>) id = foldr (.) id . reverse` so it's not even cheating, it's just folding again, `foldr (.) id (reverse $ map g $ reverse xs) i = foldr ((.).g) id xs i = foldr g i xs`.