# How to solve this Racket problem using higher order functions?

Tags: scheme, racket, primes, higher-order-functions, sieve

I am stuck on Q2.

> Q1. Write a function drop-divisible that takes a number and a list of numbers, and returns a new list containing only those numbers not "non-trivially divisible" by the the number.

This is my answer to Q1.

```
(define (drop-divisible x lst)
    (cond [(empty? lst) empty] 
    ; if the number in the list is equal to the divisor 
    ; or the number is not divisible, add it to the result list 
    [(or (= x (first lst))(< 0 (remainder (first lst) x))) (cons (first lst) (drop-divisible x (rest lst)))] 
    [else (drop-divisible x (rest lst))]))


(module+ test
(check-equal? (drop-divisible 3 (list 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)) (list 2 3 4 5 7 8 10)))
```

> Q2. Using drop-divisible and (one or more) higher order functions filter, map, foldl, foldr. (i.e. no explicit recursion), write a function that takes a list of divisors, a list of numbers to test, and applies drop-divisible for each element of the list of divisors. Here is a test your code should pass
>
> ```
> (module+ test
>     (check-equal? (sieve-with '(2 3) (list 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)) (list 2 3 5 7)))
> ```

I can come up with a snippet that only takes the second list, which does the same work as the solution to Q1.

```
(define (sieve-with divisors lst) 
    (filter (lambda (x) ((lambda (d)(or (= d x)(< 0 (remainder x d)))) divisors)) lst))
```

I tried to modify the snippet with 'map' but couldn't make it work as intended. I also can't see how 'foldr' may possibly be used here.

Comment: The key part of the question is this: "and applies `drop-divisible`..." where are you using it?

Comment: you *can* [use `map` to emulate `foldl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671186/implementing-accumulate-function-in-scheme/39681974#39681974) in R5RS Scheme, if you must. :)

Comment: `filter` is already a higher-order function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `foldl` is the right tool to use (`foldr` will also give a correct answer, albeit less efficiently, when the divisors are in increasing order). The idea is to take the input list and repeatedly applying `drop-divisible` on it, once per each element in the divisors list. Because we accumulate the result between calls, in the end we'll obtain a list filtered by *all* of the divisors. This is what I mean:

```
(define (sieve-with divisors lst)
  ; `e` is the current element from the `divisors` list
  ; `acc` is the accumulated result
  (foldl (lambda (e acc) (drop-divisible e acc))
         lst        ; initially, the accumulated result
                    ; is the whole input list
         divisors)) ; iterate over all divisors
```

I used a `lambda` to make explicit the parameter names, but in fact you can pass `drop-divisible` directly. I'd rather write this shorter implementation:

```
(define (sieve-with divisors lst)
  (foldl drop-divisible lst divisors))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(sieve-with '(2 3) '(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
=> '(2 3 5 7)
```