# Function to find all prime numbers at most n in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, primes, sieve

I'm still pretty fresh to Racket so a bit confused about this, i've created a `drop-divisible` and `sieve-with` function as shown below with some help but now need to use both to create a single function that finds all prime numbers with a given length of a list.

```
(define (drop-divisible x lst)
  (cond 
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [(or (= x (first lst)) (< 0 (remainder (first lst) x))) 
       (cons (first lst) (drop-divisible x (rest lst)))] 
    [else (drop-divisible x (rest lst))]))
```

```
(define (sieve-with divisors lst)
  (foldl (lambda (e acc) (drop-divisible e acc))
         lst divisors))
```

this is one of the test cases i need to pass

```
(module+ test
  (check-equal? (sieve 10) (list 2 3 5 7)))
```

so far ive tried to create a list using the parameter given with sieve to create a list of that size.

```
(define (sieve lst)
  ((sieve-with () (build-list (sub1 lst) (+ values 2)))))
```

getting stuck on how to get the divisors from just 10 in the test case. Thanks

Comment: Using [these functions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/number-theory.html#%28part._primes%29) is probably not allowed, right?

Comment: Would've been very useful but unfortunately not

Answer (score 1):

So your code has to pass the test

```
(check-equal? (sieve 10) (list 2 3 5 7))
```

This means, first, that `(sieve 10)` must be a valid call, and second, that it must return `(list 2 3 5 7)`, the list of primes up to `10`. `10` is a number,

```
(define (sieve n)
```

... so what do we have at our disposal? We have a number, `n` which can be e.g. `10`; we also have `(sieve-with divisors lst)`, which removes from `lst` all numbers divisible by any of the numbers in `divisors`. So we can use *that*:

```
    (sieve-with (divisors-to n)
                (list-from-to 2 n)))
```

`list-from-to` is easy to write, but what about `divisors-to`? Before we can try implementing it, we need to see how this all works together, to better get the picture of what's going on. In pseudocode,

```
(sieve n)
=
  (sieve-with (divisors-to n)
              (list-from-to 2 n))
=
  (sieve-with [d1 d2 ... dk]
              [2 3 ... n])
=
  (foldl (lambda (d acc) (drop-divisible d acc)) 
         [2 3 ... n]  [d1 d2 ... dk])
=
  (drop-divisible dk 
    (... 
      (drop-divisible d2 
        (drop-divisible d1 [2 3 ... n]))...))
```

So evidently, we can just

```
(define (divisors-to n)
  (list-from-to 2 (- n 1)))
```

and be done with it.

---

But it won't be as efficient as it can be. Only the *prime* numbers being used as the divisors should be enough. And how can we get a list of prime numbers? Why, the function `sieve` is doing exactly that:

```
(define (divisors-to n)
  (sieve (- n 1)))
```

Would this really be more efficient though, as we've intended, or less efficient? Much, much, *much* less efficient?......

But is `(- n 1)` the right limit to use here? Do we really need to test `100` by `97`, or is testing just by `7` enough (because `11 * 11 > 100`)?

And will fixing this issue also make it efficient indeed, as we've intended?......

So then, we must really have

```
(define (divisors-to n)
  (sieve (the-right-limit n)))

;; and, again,
(define (sieve n)
    (sieve-with (divisors-to n)
                (list-from-to 2 n)))
```

So  `sieve` calls `divisors-to` which calls `sieve` ... we have a vicious circle on our hands. The way to break it is to add some base case. The lists with upper limit below 4 already contain no composite numbers, namely, it's either  `()`, `(2)`, or `(2 3)`, so no divisors are needed to handle those lists, and `(sieve-with '() lst)` correctly returns `lst` anyway:

```
(define (divisors-to n)
  (if (< n 4)
    '()
    (sieve (the-right-limit n))))
```

And defining `the-right-limit` and `list-from-to` should be straightforward enough.

---

So then, as requested, the test case of `10` proceeds as follows:

```
(divisors-to 10)
=
  (sieve 3)   ; 3*3 <= 10, 4*4 > 10
=
  (sieve-with (divisors-to 3)
              (list-from-to 2 3))
=
  (sieve-with '()          ; 3 < 4
              (list 2 3))
=
  (list 2 3)
```

and, further,

```
(sieve 100)
=
  (sieve-with (divisors-to 100)
              (list-from-to 2 100))
=
  (sieve-with (sieve 10)  ; 10*10 <= 10, 11*11 > 10
              (list-from-to 2 100))
=
  (sieve-with (sieve-with (divisors-to 10)
                          (list-from-to 2 10))
              (list-from-to 2 100))
=
  (sieve-with (sieve-with (list 2 3)
                          (list-from-to 2 10))
              (list-from-to 2 100))
=
  (sieve-with (drop-divisible 3
                (drop-divisible 2
                          (list-from-to 2 10)))
              (list-from-to 2 100))
=
  (sieve-with (drop-divisible 3
                          (list 2 3 5 7 9))
              (list-from-to 2 100))
=
  (sieve-with (list 2 3 5 7)
              (list-from-to 2 100))
```

just as we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an [assignment 1 from CS2613](https://www.cs.unb.ca/%7Ebremner/teaching/cs2613/assignments/A1/). It would be helpful to add an exact description of your problems:

> Q1: drop-divisible

> Using (one or more) higher order functions filter,
> map, foldl, foldr (i.e. no explicit recursion), write a function
> drop-divisible that takes a number and a list of numbers, and returns
> a new list containing only those numbers not "non-trivially
> divisible". In particular every number trivially divides itself, but
> we don't drop 3 in the example below.

You are required to write `drop-divisible` using higher order functions (`map`, `filter`, `foldl` and so on), with no explicit recursion. Your `drop-divisible` is definitely recursive (and probably copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440017/how-to-solve-this-racket-problem-using-higher-order-functions)).

> Q2: sieve-with

> Using drop-divisible and explicit recursion write a
> function that takes a list of divisors, a list of numbers to test, and
> applies drop-divisible for each element of the list of divisors.

> Q3: sieve

> Implement a function sieve that uses sieve-with to find all
> prime numbers and most n. This should be a relatively simple wrapper
> function that just sets up the right arguments to sieve-with. Note
> that not all potential divisors need to be checked, you can speed up
> your code a lot by stopping at the square root of the number you are
> testing.

Function `sieve` will call `sieve-with` with two arguments: a list of divisors and a list of all numbers to be sieved. You will need function [`range`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29) to create these lists and also [`sqrt`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._sqrt%29%29) to get the square root of the given number.