# Work on list updated on the go in list comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, iteration, list-comprehension

I am trying to update (i.e., replace an element) of a list in a list comprehension, and then use the updated list for the next iteration of the list comprehension.

For example, in this code:

```
let n_nums = [replaceAt n (nums!!(n + 1)) nums | n <- [0..length nums]]
```

`replaceAt` always works on `nums`, whereas I would like it to work on `n_nums` from the second iteration, and then on the newly updated list on the third iteration, and so on. What is a smart way to do that?

Comment: All Haskell's objects are *immutable* so you can not *edit* a list, you make a new one.

Comment: Can you explain exactly *what* you want. As in what list do you want to generate. Not *how* you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks, I still need to wrap my head about many concepts in Haskell. In the example above, if `nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`, I would like the final result to be `n_nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`. But this is just a simple example - I would like to apply the same principle to other lists completely different from `nums`.

Comment: That looks like a `map (1+) nums`

Comment: If you however aim to "shift" the list one to the left, it is not entirely clear to me where the `6` comes from.

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to make it work with `map`. The example I wrote is only a general example, I don't need to work on it specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done with list comprehensions *(unless `zip` is used -- see below)*.

Use `scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]` or `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]` or `mapAccumL :: (acc -> x -> (acc, y)) -> acc -> [x] -> (acc, [y])` and other related state-passing higher-order functions, for that.  `iterate` with `(!! n)` over its result is probably the best fit here. Or `scanl` over the list of indices `[1..n]`. Or something like that.

Of course hand-coded recursive code is always an option.

*On the second thought,* using `zip`, the input can be paired up with the result shifted by one notch through the use of `tail`, then this zipped result can be drawn from in a list comprehension ... to create the result!

See [the supposedly impossible definition of `sum` in terms of `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951590/849891) (which also uses `zip` and `last`).