# decimal integer to Base4 string Haskell

Tags: haskell, radix

I'm trying to convert an integer from decimal integer to a string based on base 4, but my unfoldr doesn't work and I'm not sure why or how to replace it. I can't use imports either. Please help me fix this.

```
dec2Base4 :: Int -> String
dec2Base4 = map i2c . reverse . unfoldr decomp
    where
    decomp n = if n == 0 then Nothing else Just(n `mod` 4, n `div` 4)
    i2c i = if i == 0 then '0' else if i == 1 then '1' else if i == 2 then '2' else '3'
```

Example: `dec2Base4 10-> "22"`

Comment: Works for me. What goes wrong for you?

Comment: `$ghc -O2 --make *.hs -o main -threaded -rtsopts
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:46:33: error:
    • Variable not in scope:
        unfoldr
          :: (Integer -> Maybe (Integer, Integer)) -> Int -> [Integer]
    • Perhaps you meant ‘foldr’ (imported from Prelude)`

Comment: are you allowed to use `iterate`? `scanl`? `unfoldr` can be implemented in terms of both (or with direct recursion). `scanl` can be implemented in terms of [`zip` and `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951590/849891)...

Comment: meta: if you have several accounts you can ask moderators to unite the accounts into one. (I'm not sure about the exact procedure).

Comment: You could start with an auxiliary string obtained thru recursion:  `let { auxStr 0 = "" ; auxStr n = let (q,r) = divMod n 4 in (i2c r) : (auxStr q) }`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically OK, but it would need you to import the [`unfoldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) function from the `Data.List` package.

The fact that you are banned from using `import` clauses might just mean that the *powers that be* want you to use plain recursion.

### A recursion-based solution:

Unfortunately, recursion will naturally produce the least significant digit (rightmost digit) first, because this rightmost digit is essentially `mod n 4`. You will have to use the `reverse` function to correct that, just like in your library-based code.

For example, without the help of any non-Prelude library functions, the `dec2Base4` function can be written like this:

```
dec2Base4 :: Int -> String
dec2Base4 n
    |  (n < 0)    =  '-' : (reverse (auxStr (-n)))
    |  (n == 0)   =  "0"
    |  otherwise  =  reverse (auxStr n)  -- when n > 0
  where
    i2c i     =  "0123" !! i
    auxStr 0  =  ""
    auxStr n  =  let  (q,r) = (divMod n 4)  in  (i2c r) : (auxStr q)
```

### Testing code:

```
unitTest :: Int -> IO ()
unitTest n = do
    let res = dec2Base4 n
    putStrLn $ "Result for " ++ (show n) ++ " is: " ++ res

main = do
    let  testList = [0,11,2051,-2051]
    mapM_  unitTest  testList
```

### Test program output:

```
Result for 0 is: 0
Result for 11 is: 23
Result for 2051 is: 200003
Result for -2051 is: -200003
```

Comment: with tail recursion there's no need to reverse. consider `auxStr n acc =  let  (q,r) = (divMod n 4)  in  auxStr q (i2c r : acc)`. :)