# haskell function that takes an integer and returns string representing that number in binary

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a haskell function that will take in an integer and returns a a number in binary.

```
num2bits :: Integral a => a -> [Char]
num2bits 0 = ['0'] num2bits n | n `mod` 2 == 1 = num2bits (n `div` 2) ++ ['1'] | n `mod` 2 == 0 = num2bits (n `div` 2) ++ ['0']
```

Comment: It looks like your code is not properly indented.

Comment: How is that a typo, if a person didn't type in the whole code correctly, and instead made a systematic mistake?

Comment: @Nicole I've rolled back your edit as it invalidates the answer.  this isn't allowed. :) I've previously rolled back my own similar edit for the same reason, as it changes the very essence of your question.... or was it really just a typo?

Comment: Similar to [SO question 67178663](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178663/decimal-integer-to-base4-string-haskell). The spurious leading zero can be avoided using an auxiliary function that returns an empty string for zero input.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is improperly formatted.

Once you correct this, it works (except for always including a superfluous leading `'0'`).

Each clause of a definition should start on its own line, all of them at the same indentation level. All the guards of a clause must be indented more than the clause itself.

Comment: I corrected that. Thank you much.  Can you explain to me what you mean by the superflouous leading 0?

Comment: @NicoleMartinez `num2bits 15` produces `"01111"` and `num2bits 15` produces `"0100"`.